# Get user input and output Flask and HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x, flask

I'm trying to develop a web-app with Flask and HTML and right now I need to get the user input, pass it to the Python back-end, execute a function and return its output, placing it inside an HTML element. I also want this to happen without refreshing the HTML page.

How can I do this? 
Bellow I have the code that I've developed so far but it's not working correctly:

My HTML:

```
           <div id="ThroughputRate" class="data_entry">
                <form action="{{ url_for('background_check_throughputrate') }}" method="post">
                    <input name="throughput_rate_text" class="input_box">
                    <input id="checkThroughputRate" type="submit" class='new-button-data' value="Check Throughput Rate">
                    <output name="throughputRateResult" class="result_box" ></output>
                </form>
            </div>
```

My Flask backend:

```
@app.route('/background_check_throughputrate', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def background_check_throughputrate():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.form['throughput_rate_text']
        processed_text = str(text)
        throughput = transition_throughput_rate(processed_text)
        return jsonify(throughput)
```

My HTML (continuation to get the output of the function executed on Flask):

```
    <script type=text/javascript>
            $(function() {
              $('a#checkThroughputRate').bind('click', function() {
                $.getJSON('/background_check_throughputrate', function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
                  document.getElementById('throughputRateResult').innerHTML = data;
                });
                return false;
              });
            });
    </script>
```

The idea behind my execution is that the user uses the first snippet of code (in HTML) to insert the input, this input is passed onto the second snippet of code (in flask) and finally, the output of the function is passed onto the last snippet of code (in JS inside HTML) so that it can be displayed on the corresponding HTML element.

So far, the input is being correctly processed inside flask but the issue is that when the function returns the jsonify, it appears on the screen, instead of sending it into the frontend. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is designed to load the JSON data from endpoint using GET request, however, your Python code example responds to only POST requests.

Here is the working code:

HTML

```html
<div id="ThroughputRate" class="data_entry">
    <form action="{{ url_for('background_check_throughputrate') }}" method="post" id="throughputRateForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input name="throughput_rate_text" class="input_box">
        <input id="checkThroughputRate" type="submit" class='new-button-data' value="Check Throughput Rate">
        <output id="throughputRateResult" class="result_box" ></output>
    </form>
</div>
```

Python

```py
@app.route('/background_check_throughputrate', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def background_check_throughputrate():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.form['throughput_rate_text']
        processed_text = str(text)
        throughput = transition_throughput_rate(processed_text)
        return jsonify(throughput)
```

JavaScript

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#throughputRateForm').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $(this)[0];
            var formData = new FormData(form);

            $.ajax({
                url: '/background_check_throughputrate',
                method: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    document.getElementById('throughputRateResult').innerHTML = data;
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, this code blindly trusts the user input and displays it on the webpage which can result to Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) and that is not good!

Avoid using `innerHTML` property when displaying user input, because it can be used to inject malicious HTML tags (e.g. `<script>`), i would highly recommend using `innerText` property instead.

Comment: Thank you ver much! :)